# iotop on Centos 5.8 - OSError: Netlink error: Invalid argument (22)

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

When I'm attempting to run iotop on Centos 5.8 (kernel 2.6.32.9) I'm receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/iotop", line 16, in ?
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 567, in main
    main_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 557, in <lambda>
    main_loop = lambda: run_iotop(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 465, in run_iotop
    return curses.wrapper(run_iotop_window, options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/curses/wrapper.py", line 44, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/ui.py", line 457, in run_iotop_window
    process_list = ProcessList(taskstats_connection, options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/data.py", line 375, in __init__
    self.update_process_counts()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/data.py", line 431, in update_process_counts
    stats = self.taskstats_connection.get_single_task_stats(thread)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/data.py", line 158, in get_single_task_stats
    reply = self.connection.recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/iotop/netlink.py", line 229, in recv
    raise err
OSError: Netlink error: Invalid argument (22)
```

iotop was installed by just using `yum install iotop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to correct this error with the following steps

1. Remove iotop installed by yum - `yum remove iotop`
2. Install python 2.6 - `yum install python26`
3. Install iotop rpm - `rpm -ivh http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/files/iotop-0.4.1-1.noarch.rpm`
4. Edit /usr/bin/iotop

   - Edit first line `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.6`
5. Run `iotop` and enjoy

Comment: In your opinion, is the iotop utility worth all of this hassle?

Comment: Can you suggest another one @RogerHalliburton ?

Comment: edit /usr/bin/iotop?